# Why is user data not being stored into studio3t?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am having the hardest time understanding what is going wrong. I am building an app that takes user email and password then stores it in a data base. problem: the user password is storing but the user email is not making it to where no one can log in because their email is not in the database. I am using mongoose and studio3T. I am posting my code as well.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});



userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: process.env.SECRET, encryptedFields: ['password'] });

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("secrets");
        }
    });
});
app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                if (foundUser.password === password) {
                    res.render("secrets");
                }
            }
        }
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that req.body.email really contains a value when it is called. I assume the field is called something else. Since you didn‘t specify this field as required in your schema, it will be saved even without this field.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer which I came to with your help. Thank you. I found my mistake was in my code. I commented where I made the mistake

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});



userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: process.env.SECRET, encryptedFields: ['password'] });

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    const newUser = new User({
      ////////////////////////////was req.body.email////////////////////////
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("secrets");
        }
    });
});
app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                if (foundUser.password === password) {
                    res.render("secrets");
                }
            }
        }
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```